# JPA ManyToMany ConcurrentModificationException issues

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

We have three entities with bidirectional many-to-many mappings in a A <-> B <-> C "hierarchy" like so (simplified, of course):

```
@Entity
Class A {
  @Id int id;
  @JoinTable(
    name = "a_has_b",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
  @ManyToMany
  Collection<B> bs;
}

@Entity
Class B {
  @Id int id;
  @JoinTable(
    name = "b_has_c",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "c_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
  @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
    cascade=CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
  @org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
  private Collection<C> cs;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bs", fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
    cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,  CascadeType.REFRESH})
  @org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
  private Collection<A> as;
}

@Entity
Class C {
  @Id int id;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cs", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, 
    cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,  CascadeType.REFRESH})
  @org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
  private Collection<B> bs;
}
```

There's no conecpt of an orphan - the entities are "standalone" from the application's point of view - and most of the time we're going to have a fistful of A:s, each with a couple of B:s (some may be "shared" among the A:s), and some 1000 C:s, not all of which are always "in use" by any B. We've concluded that we need bidirectional relations, since whenever an entity instance is removed, all links (entries in the join tables) have to be removed too. That is done like this:

```
void removeA( A a ) {
  if ( a.getBs != null ) {
    for ( B b : a.getBs() ) {  //<--------- ConcurrentModificationException here
      b.getAs().remove( a ) ;
      entityManager.merge( b );
    }
  }
  entityManager.remove( a );
}
```

If the collection, `a.getBs()` here, contains more than one element, then a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown. I've been banging my head for a while now, but can't think of a reasonable way of removing the links without meddling with the collection, which makes underlying the `Iterator` angry.

Q1: How am I supposed to do this, given the current ORM setup? (If at all...)

Q2: Is there a more reasonable way do design the OR-mappings that will let JPA (provided by Hibernate in this case) take care of everything. It'd be just swell if we didn't have to include those `I'll be deleted now, so everybody I know, listen carefully: you don't need to know about this!`-loops, which aren't working anyway, as it stands...

Comment: This was very useful for me:  https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/fix-ConcurrentModificationException-java-fail-safe-fast-solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the collection, `a.getBs()` here, contains more than one element, then a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown

The issue is that the collections inside of A, B, and C are magical Hibernate collections so when you run the following statement:

```
b.getAs().remove( a );
```

this removes a from b's collection but it *also* removes b from a's list which happens to be the collection being iterated over in the for loop.  That generates the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Matt's solution should work if you are really removing all elements in the collection.  If you aren't however another work around is to copy all of the b's into a collection which removes the magical Hibernate collection from the process.

```
// copy out of the magic hibernate collection to a local collection
List<B> copy = new ArrayList<>(a.getBs());
for (B b : copy) {
   b.getAs().remove(a) ;
   entityManager.merge(b);
}
```

That should get you a little further down the road.

Comment: I think you really only need to remove the mapping from the owner side.

Comment: This idea, using a detached collection (I actually did it even uglier and passed the collection as a parameter to the `removeX` methods) finally does the job. It means another DB roundtrip but for the time being, we can live with that. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked @Gustav.  I don't see how it will result in another DB roundtrip however.  There is one with the getBs() which you were doing before and one for each remove which you were also doing before.  I'm not sure if the merge will generate a db call.

Answer (score 5):

This problem has nothing to do with the ORM, as far as I can tell. **You cannot use the syntactic-sugar `foreach` construct in Java to remove an element from a collection.**

> Note that `Iterator.remove` is the *only* safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress.

[Source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html)

*Simplified example of the problematic code:*

```
List<B> bs = a.getBs();
for (B b : bs)
{
    if (/* some condition */)
    {
        bs.remove(b); // throws ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

You **must** use the `Iterator` version to remove elements while iterating. *Correct implementation:*

```
List<B> bs = a.getBs();
for (Iterator<B> iter = bs.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
{
    B b = iter.next();
    if (/* some condition */)
    {
        iter.remove(); // works correctly
    }
}
```

---

*Edit:* I think this will work; untested however. If not, you should stop seeing `ConcurrentModificationException`s but instead (I think) you'll see `ConstraintViolationException`s.

```
void removeA(A a)
{
    if (a != null)
    {
        a.setBs(new ArrayList<B>()); // wipe out all of a's Bs
        entityManager.merge(a);      // synchronize the state with the database
        entityManager.remove(a);     // removing should now work without ConstraintViolationExceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But is that really what's going on in my case? I don't see that I'm explicitly modifying the `Collection` iterated over, but rather removing stuff from <b>its</b> member field (a `Collection`). Does `EntityManager.merge(T t)` affect the `Iterator` which gave me the `t`?

Comment: @Gustav: _Does `EntityManager.merge(T t)` affect the `Iterator` which gave me the `t`?_ Honestly, I can't say for sure, without testing it. There's a lot that goes on under the hood when using `EntityManager` (this is mostly a good thing). **N.B.** I had a small (but significant) typo in my answer. The second `bs.remove(b)` should have been `iter.remove()`. That said, when removing an `A a`, _I think that you only need to remove_ `a`'s `B`s. See my edit; I think it will suffice.

Comment: @Matt: This does indeed seem very reasonable. It doesn't quite work as expected though: when I do what you suggest in your edit, I get a `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: [<type.of.A.here>#<null>]`. Without the `remove`, the join table entries are deleted nicely, so your idea of just wiping clean on one side of the relation does that part of the job! However, I've tried playing around with `flush()` ing before the `remove()` a.s.o., but it still won't work the whole way... Seen this before?

Comment: @Gustav: which call throws the exception? `entityManager.remove(a);`? I'm not sure, off the top of my head - but try changing `entityManager.merge(a);` to `entityManager.persist(a);`.

Comment: @Gustav: I just remembered that `merge()` returns a copy of the object you pass in, so try `remove()`-ing _that_ one: `entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(a));`

Comment: @Matt: Thanks for great input. I finally got it working now, using something along Gray's idea with a detached collection, but this sure was a valuable and interesting lesson. I'd love to grok deeper into the data modeling and try to get it to work with a "cleaner" annotation setup, but that'll have to wait, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Gray's solution worked! Fortunately for us the JPA people seem to have been trying to implement collections as close to official Sun documentation on the proper use of `List<>` collections has indicated:

> Note that Iterator.remove is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress.

I was all but pulling out my hair over this exception thinking it meant one `@Stateless` method could not call another `@Stateless` method from it's own class. This I thought odd as I was sure that I read somewhere that nested transactions are allowed. So when I did a search on this very exception, I found this posting and applied Gray's solution. Only in my case I happened to have two independent collections that had to be handled. As Gray indicated, according the Java spec on the proper way to remove from a member from a Java container, you need to use a copy of the original container to iterate with and then do your `remove()` on the original container which makes a lot of sense. Otherwise, the original container's link list algorithm gets confused.

```
    for ( Participant p2 : new ArrayList<Participant>( p1.getFollowing() )) {
        p1.getFollowing().remove(p2);
        getEm().merge(p1);
        p2.getFollowers().remove(p1);
        getEm().merge(p2);
    }
```

Notice I only make a copy of the first collection (`p1.getFollowing()`) and not the second collection (`p2.getFollowers()`). That is because I only need to iterate from one collection even though I need to remove associations from both collections.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand how this answers or relates to any of the questions.